# How would allow for a string input that doesn't need to be exact for my program to run in a If & Else statement?

Tags: python

So here is my situation, I am trying to make a pretty basic text-based adventure RPG game as something to just get used to If & Else statements etc. What I am wondering is why I can use the `"for letter in 'word'"` to pretty much prepare my program for any general input made by the user. For example, If I ask the player if they are ready to begin(Y/N): Instead of the user being forced to put a capital Y or a or a capital N for the program to work without an error, how would I generalize it where they can put anything like "YesYESyeaYEAYEAHyeahSUREsure" etc so if the program sees any sequence of those letters it will still work as if the inputted "Y" I'm not the best at explaining things so if there are any questions feel free to ask. The code I am currently working with is below! :)

```
try:
    import time
    import sys
except ImportError:
    pass
loadSeq = False
startSeq = ""
while startSeq != 'Y' or startSeq != 'y':
    startSeq = str(input("Start Message: Are you ready to begin? "))
    for letter in 'YESyes':
        if startSeq == 'Y':

            Code here

        elif startSeq == str('N') or startSeq == str('n'):

            Code here

        else:
            break
```

Comment: Couldn't you just convert the input to lower case, then just check against lower case?

Comment: Yeah that would work if it was a Yes or No but I'm trying to see if theres a way where It would also accept other forms of Yes and No... since people don't always follow instructions like that. "Sure, yea, yeah, ye," Typos etc.

Comment: Scrape a list of [yes synonyms](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/yes) and check against that?

Comment: @MichaelGuajardo You would have to have a set of all the words that you want to allow, then check for membership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to add all acceptable answers to a list:

`startSeq = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']`

Then change this line:

`while startSeq != 'Y' or startSeq != 'y':`

To this:

`while word.lower() in startSeq:`

To check for a bunch of different 'start' words. The .lower() makes it so 'Yes', 'YES', and 'yes' all would be true if 'yes' was in startSeq